# Issue updating react table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tanstack

I am using @tanstack/react-table and I want to use the table to display a list for me.

The list of rows comes as a prop (data)

```
const TableComponent = ({
    columnFilters,
    setColumnFilters,
    columns,
    data,
.... the rest of props
})
```

I am using this few lines to create the table variable:

```
const table = useReactTable({
        data,
        columns,
        state: {
            rowSelection,
            globalFilter,
            columnFilters,
            pagination
        },
        onPaginationChange: setPagination,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        onRowSelectionChange: setRowSelection,
        onColumnFiltersChange: setColumnFilters,
        getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
        getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
        getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
        onGlobalFilterChange: setGlobalFilter,
        debugTable: false
    })
```

and then using `table.getRowModel().rows.map` to display the rows.

After I change data in the parent component, I do a console log inside the table component. I see the data is changed but the `table.getRowModel().rows` is still log the old data.

Any idea what is right way to change the data, that affect the body of the table also.